# npx create-react-app only creates node modules,package.json ,yarn.lock and dose not create the other files

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm using
Node v14.3.0  npm 6.14.5 yarn 1.22.4 and even not set create-react-app globally but i'm still not able to create a react project.I have even uninstalled node and yarn but still it does not work.Here are the screenshots of my terminal.

[screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSCHj.png)

Comment: Terminal output looks fine, project created. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Is there no `src` folder inside `my-app` folder?

Comment: But shouldnt the terminal output should say something like move into the project folder and run npm start happy hacking?

Comment: Yes there isnt src or public folder inside the my-app folder

Comment: have you tried using `npx create-react-app reactapplication` ?

Comment: its the same bro just the name of app is different in your case

Comment: I have never seen such a problem. Can you try using a template `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` or `npx create-react-app my-app --template rich`?

Comment: yes i have tried but the problem remains

Comment: Your node, npm versions are fine. Try: 1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`  2. `npx create-react-app app-name` Before 2 you can try clearing npm cache for your windows machine. Also, please read this [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) as you try again. You can use `npx`, `npm` or `yarn` explained there. try that

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and using `npx react-native@latest` solved that for me, as suggested here:
https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1063#issuecomment-1267244399

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33536668)